# import 'library' as variable throws error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to play with ES6 in a project. I'm using mocha and supertest but I dont know how to import supertest

The original import was

```
var request = require('supertest');
```

I've tryed with different approches without success

```
import 'supertest' as request // syntax error
import * as request from 'supertest' // request is a object no a functiion
import request from 'supertest' // TypeError: undefined is not a function

request(app).get(...)
```

Comment: AFAIK, only lines 2 and 3 are valid syntax. However, `supertest` doesn't appear to have ES6 module support, so I wouldn't expect this to work.

Comment: How do the `supertest` exports look like?

Comment: line 4 should work. `supertest` will be search in the `node_modules` folder. if it is an own file you have to write the relativ path like `./supertest`.

Comment: So I have to wait for supertest implements ES6 support,I thought I could use the modules transparently in ES6 :(

Answer (score 0):

in a test_helper file:

```
import sinon from 'sinon'
import chai from 'chai'

var supertest = require("supertest");

module.exports = {
  sinon: sinon,
  chai: chai,
  supertest: supertest
}
```

Then in your test file, you can do

```
import {sinon, chai, supertest} from '../test_helper'
```